# How to use Chaos Monkey on local cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, monkey, resiliency

I have a cluster back in my office for testing purposes. I have there a database and i would like to make all kind of "monekybusiness" to those test machines, long before i want to go to production.

I zipped 2-3 coffees all this morning trying to figure out HOW to make the "inFAMOUS" Simian Army to chew my nerves here on my local machines.

Everywhere i read, saw all kind of setups for AWS.

Question : Is there a possibility to deploy the Monkeys on my local cluster? Or is there any other alternative to Simian Army?

Answer (score 1):

What is the question that you want to answer with your tests?

[ChaosMonkey](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/chaos-monkey-released-into-wild.html) is a resilience tool that was design for the cloud, its main purpose is to verify that AWS' Auto Scaling Groups (ASG) will be able to re-provision faulty/offline nodes and that the application is capable to perform in a stable way when this process is being done. Do you have an automated process like this in your local cluster?

Comment: I want some kind of tool that can put this kind of failover test over my cluster. Let`s say i have a 30 machines cluster that i want to play with. Will my application still be up and serve clients during different outages!?